# R Programming - Trying to read files in the directory using function

Tags: r, csv

I am writing R program to read multiple csv file one by one using functions.
It works if i give `read.csv` command alone in that working directory but it never works if i pass the name of the file as parameter.

For example

```
dat <- function (x)  
 {     
awr <- data.table(read.csv(x))
  }
```

I passed

```
dat("raja.csv")
```

The unfortunate thing is it is not throwing any error and the awr data set is not getting created.

If i give

```
awr <- data.table(read.csv("raja.csv")) ..it works...
```

Am not able to figure out why its not working when passed in the function.
I checked the working directory using `getwd()`. it is same...

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning anything from your function. This should do it:

```
dat <- function (x) data.table(read.csv(x))
```

Originally you were assigning the contents of the file to `awr` but not returning `awr`.

Comment: that doesnt matter. run this `tmp <- function(x) y <- x; (var <- tmp(5))`

Comment: Yes but in the original example nothing is being assigned to the function result. `dat("raja.csv")` will not print anything before I've modified the function. If the poster had done `x <- dat("raja.csv")` that would be different.

Comment: @rawr But if you just run `dat("raja.csv")` the result is returned invisibly so it doesn't look like anything happend. Though `.Last.value` should have the contents.

Comment: In summary @user3745215, your function is probably working as expected. It's just that when you previewed it by typing `dat("raja.csv")` the results are not printed to your console. If you were to assign the results of that function to a variable however, it should work as you want. Overall though, I would recommend using the solution I posted, which is more explicit in what will be returned.

Comment: so we all three agree that your answer doesn't matter and doesn't address the question. cool

Comment: I agree that running either version will return the data table, but the issue has always been that the result wasnt assigned, whether returned invisibly or explicitly. the answer should mention something about assignments. thx